# how can use of a function in several ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For avoid repeating i want a function use in several ajax call. how is it?

**Like:**

```
//use of content this function in other function(ajax call)
$(function num_bg () {
    var total = $('.pag a', '.ser').size();
    if (total == 0) {
        $('.number').css('display','none');
    }
});

// First ajax call
    function pagination(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataObj = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: 'dirc',
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            var $html = $(html);
                $('#num_count').replaceWith($html.find('#num_count'));
                $('tr#paginate').replaceWith($html.find('tr#paginate'));
                $('.pagination').replaceWith($html.find('.pagination'))
                $('#erro_find').remove();

        num_bg (); // This is same function above (this don't work)
        }
    });
    return false;
}
$('form').live('change', pagination);
$('.pag a').live('click', pagination);
$('#input').live('keyup', pagination);


 //Second ajax call
$('#delete').click(function(e){        
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'diuarsl',
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            var $html = $(html);                       
                    $('#num').replaceWith($html.find('#num_count'));
                    $('tr#pag').replaceWith($html.find('tr#paginate'));
                    $('.pag').replaceWith($html.find('.pagination'));

                num_bg (); // This is same function above (this don't work)
                }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have your function wrapped up in a closure. Closures are useful this way, since it means you're not polluting any other namespace with your variables (e.g. the window).

Remove the `$(...)` around your newbg function.

```
  // num_bg is now available as a global
function num_bg () {
    var total = $('.pag a', '.ser').size();
    if (total == 0) {
        $('.number').css('display','none');
    }
}

$( num_bg ); // invoke the function when the DOM is ready
```

The `$(function() { });` in jQuery will attach a handler to the DOM ready event. Usually if you're using the DOM then you'd want to wrap all the code in it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `$(..)` call around the Function Expression (and make it a Function Declaration).